# Make Dynamic Dropdown List Based on Column Values with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

How do I create a dynamic dropdown list based on a range of values in column B by using VBA code?

The data are from column B in Sheet 1. I want to make the dropdown list on cell A2 in Sheet 2.

This is the example of the data set in Sheet 1 (Name = Column A; Level = Column B)

| Name | Level |
| --- | --- |
| John | Level 1 |
| Mike | Level 1 |
| Lewis | Level 2 |
| Harry | Level 3 |

When one of the lists is selected it would copy the data to column B in Sheet 2.

For example: when "Level 1" is chosen, then VBA will copy John and Mike to column B in Sheet 2.

Comment: How to be returned the names for the example you required? Should be John and Mike names in the same cell, separated by comma, to be on different lines of the same cell? To be placed one on top of the other, on the next cell **each time you change the level in "A2**? Or how?

Comment: Hi, I want to make it into different row. John will be in the first row and followed by Mike.

Comment: And how to proceed next time you select a different level? To delete existing and write the corresponding names or to add after existing?

Comment: I wish to delete the existing and write the corresponding name

Comment: Please, try the solution I posted yesterday and send some feedback.

Comment: i'll try the solution tomorrow. I'm sorry for the late response. Thank you so much

Comment: Didn't you find some time to test the code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Answer (score 2):

Please, try the next solution, in the next way:

1. Copy the next code in the sheet code module **where the list validated cell exists**. To do that, right click on the respective sheet name, choose `View Code` and paste it in the window which appears. In this way any cell modification in the respective sheet will trigger the `Change` event:

```
Option Explicit

Private dict As Object

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Const changedCell As String = "A2" 'address where the validated list cell exists
  If Target.address(0, 0) = changedCell Then 'the code works only if changedCell is changed...
    Dim lastRBB As Long, shNames As Worksheet, arr
    Set shNames = Worksheets("Sheet1")'set the sheet where from the data to be collected exists
    lastRBB = shNames.Range("B" & shNames.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row in column B:B
    arr = shNames.Range("A2:B" & lastRBB).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster processing
    If dict Is Nothing Then   'if the dictionary has not been loaded (yet):
        loadTheDictionary arr 'call the sub loading the dictionary
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = False 'to avoid the event to be triggered again
      Target.Offset(0, 1).Resize(lastRBB).ClearContents 'clear more than enough rows...
      Target.Offset(0, 1).Resize(UBound(dict(Target.value)) + 1).Value2 = _
                                Application.Transpose(dict(Target.value))
    Application.EnableEvents = True  'to prepare the next change event (to be triggered)
  End If
End Sub

Sub loadTheDictionary(arr)
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim arrIt, i As Long
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 2)) Then
        dict(arr(i, 2)) = Array(arr(i, 1))
    Else
        arrIt = dict(arr(i, 2)) 'in order to change a dictionary array item you need
                                'to extract it in a variable, to add/eliminate something
                                'then to place it back as item:
        ReDim Preserve arrIt(UBound(arrIt) + 1) 'increase the 1D array dimension with one unit
        arrIt(UBound(arrIt)) = arr(i, 1)        'place the following name in the array laste element
        dict(arr(i, 2)) = arrIt                 'load back the processed array
    End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

Now, try playing with selecting different options in list validated cell ("A2").

If you often change the used levels, I can also supply a piece of code able to create a such list data validated cell, placing in it the unique levels...

Answer (score 1):

- Right click on sheet2 tab > `View Code` > paste code in sheet module
- `visRng` is the visible range after apply fiter
- `rCell` is the first blank cell on Col B

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144111)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Worksheet.ShowAllData method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.showalldata?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm175126)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.SpecialCells method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144203)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .Address = "$A$2" Then
            If Len(.Value) > 0 Then
                Dim oSht As Worksheet: Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1")
                If oSht.AutoFilterMode Then
                    If oSht.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then oSht.ShowAllData
                End If
                Dim rCell As Range, visRng As Range
                With oSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
                    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Target.Value
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set visRng = .Columns(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    If Not visRng Is Nothing Then
                        Set rCell = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)
                        If Len(rCell.Value) > 0 Then Set rCell = rCell.Offset(1)
                        Application.EnableEvents = False
                        visRng.Copy rCell
                        Application.EnableEvents = True
                        oSht.ShowAllData
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your help! Could you please explain a bit about set visiRng and rCell because i'm having trouble to implement it to the actual data.

Comment: I've updated the answer. You may need to read the MS doc to understand the code.

Comment: I tried the VBA using example above. But, VBA doesn't give any results when dropdown list is selected. Is there any steps i should do to create the dropdown list so that it will give returns?

Comment: No. As I mentioned in my answer, the code should be stored in `sheet module`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need vba to do this. Steps:

1. use "unique" function to create a unique list of level col
2. Setup validation picklist on the cell A2 using the above unique values
3. Use "Filter" function in B2 on sheet 2 syntax => =Filter(range to return, range to lookup = A1)

Comment: sadly my office's excel is not supported with Unique and Filter Functions. Thank you for the suggestion